# windows server 2008 dns and optaining static ip addresses

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, ip-address

In our office we are using windows server 2008 as domain server. There are about 40 machines.

I would like to change my PC network settings from "Obtain Ip address automatically" to specific ip address. (Ex: 192.168.1.58) Because I would like to have additional ip addresses to test different websites locally.

Will it create any issue in future that I reserve those ip adresses? For example will domain server try to give same ip address to some other machine? Would it create any conflict in future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it could cause issues if you assign any ip addresses that are encompassed by the DHCP scope on the DHCP server. DHCP address conflict detection should deal with this if it's enabled but you can't guarantee that. Also, this is not really about DNS, it's about DHCP.

You really don't need to assign multiple ip addresses just for the purpose of testing web sites. You could use host headers with hosts file entries for each test site or you could run the test sites on different ports.

Answer (score 1):

No, you shouldn't have any problems if you do a reservation via the DHCP console. The DHCP service will not assign that address to any machine other than the one you've reserved it for.

However, if you manually assign an address that's part of the DHCP scope, then yes, you could have problems.

In my experience, it is simpler to handle reservations/static through the DHCP server than it is to maintain separate DHCP/static blocks.

HTH